# Impact of copy of windows on IIS

Tags: iis

I published our companies website on IIS7 both on Dev and production, it works fine on the dev environment, but on production IE stops rendering the popup after you click to open it a couple of times.This does not happen in chrome or any other browser except IE.

The only different between the servers is that the production sever does not have a genuine copy of windows server R2. Could it be the reason why IE is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Simlpe answer - no. I hate the genuine stuff myself (not advocating picary - I have a couple of VM's that jzust decidded they are not genuine despite a KMS in the system).

It does some things, but it does not change IIS behavior, espeically not in regards to IE only.